# maximum time step of IDA solver in Open Modelica

Tags: ida, openmodelica, timestep

In Open Modelica, in the settings of IDA solver, we can define the initial and maximum time step as well. In a simulation, I have set these parameters, but after simulation and checking the solutions points, I found the IDA has not bounded to the defined maximum time step. is there anyone to advise me why the parameter did not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can check which maximum allowed step size your simulation executable is using by adding `-lv=LOG_SOLVER` to the simulation flags and search in the log for `maximum step size`. If its not there IDA will be use with the default setting.

To change the maximum step size for IDA you can't use [-maxstepsize](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html#simflag-maxstepsize), it's not implemented for IDA.
I had to check the source code to find out how to do it correctly. It's possible but way to complicated.

You need to:

- Disable equidistant time step with [-noEquidistantTimeGrid](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html#simflag-noequidistanttimegrid)
- Set a value to [-noEquidistantOutputTime=value](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html#simflag-noequidistantoutputtime)

---

So the following example script will use IDA with a maximum stepsize of π to simulate a pendulum from the MSL:

```
loadModel(Modelica); getErrorString();
setCommandLineOptions("-d=newInst"); getErrorString();
simulate(Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Examples.Elementary.Pendulum, method="ida", simflags="-noEquidistantOutputTime=3.14159265358979 -noEquidistantTimeGrid -lv=LOG_SOLVER"); getErrorString();
```

Save this script to `runTest.mos` and run it with omc `$omc runTest.mos &> some.log`.
Check `some.log` and you will find

```bash
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | recognized solver: ida
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | Initializing IDA DAE Solver
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | ## IDA ## Initializing solver of size 2 .
|                 | |       | | The relative tolerance is 1e-06. Following absolute tolerances are used for the states: 
|                 | |       | | IDA uses internal root finding method YES
|                 | |       | | Maximum integration order 5
|                 | |       | | use equidistant time grid NO
|                 | |       | | maximum step size 3.14159
|                 | |       | | as the output frequency control is used: 0
|                 | |       | | as the output frequency time step control is used: 3.141593
|                 | |       | | IDA linear solver method selected ida use sparse direct solver KLU. (default)
|                 | |       | | Jacobian is calculated by \"Colored numerical Jacobian, which is default for dassl and ida. With option -idaLS=klu a sparse matrix is used.\"
|                 | |       | | initial step size is set automatically.
```

You can do the same in OMedit with the simflags `-noEquidistantOutputTime=3.14159265358979 -noEquidistantTimeGrid` added to your simulation.

---

Note:
Of course this is ridiculous and the documentation of [-maxstepsize](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html#simflag-maxstepsize) is wrong:

> Value specifies maximum absolute step size, used by the methods: dassl, ida.

Please open a ticket about this on the [OpenModelica GitHub](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica) so it get's fixed.